# Proguard doesn't obfuscate class without saying so

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

I am building an android library and I use a utility class in which all methods are static. This class is used internally and is not meant to be used by the library users. I am using proguard to obfuscate the code and I don't want to expose the utility class. When I use proguard, it retains the class name as such and obfuscates the methods inside it. I have not specifically excluded that class with -keep.

Here's generic part of my proguard config

```
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod,MethodParameters,LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable

//Preserve all annotations.

-keepattributes *Annotation*

// Preserve all .class method names.

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

// Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

// Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

// Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
// is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
// You can comment this out if your library doesn't use serialization.
// If your code contains serializable classes that have to be backward
// compatible, please refer to the manual.

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

EDIT: "-whyareyoukeeping" says I am invoking a method in utility class from another class(which extends Service) which is excluded from obfuscation.

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: Proguard not obfuscation a class completely. I have also updated my question to include more details.

Comment: I still can't catch your question. You just said you know why ProGuard is keeping one class, but you still have a questoin?

Comment: If an un-obfuscated method uses a utility class then the utility class is also not obfuscated. Is this the expected behavior of proguard?

Comment: You said it extends and unobfuscated class, so yes, the behaviour is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't aware of this behavior